# Js обработчик

Tags: ajax, формы, отправка

Здравствуйте не могу понять в чем дело вот php файл

```
﻿<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Данные два файла нужно включать только в случае определения INCLUDE_CHECK

session_name('tzLogin');
// Запуск сессии

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Устанавливаем время жизни куки 2 недели

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['tzRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // Если вы вошли в систему, но куки tzRemember (рестарт браузера) отсутствует
    // и вы не отметили чекбокс 'Запомнить меня':

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Удалаяем сессию
}

if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: demo.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Войти')
{
    // Проверяем, что представлена форма Войти

    $err = array();
    // Запоминаем ошибки

    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'Все поля должны быть заполнены!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Получаем все ввденые данные

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // Если все в порядке - входим в систему

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Сохраняем некоторые данные сессии

            setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Ошибочный пароль или/и имя пользователя!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Сохраняем сообщение об ошибке сессии

    header("Location: demo.php");
    exit;
}
else if($_POST['submit']=='Зарегистрироваться')
{
    // Проверяем, что представлена форма Зарегистрироваться

    $err = array();

    if(strlen($_POST['username'])<4 || strlen($_POST['username'])>32)
    {
        $err[]='Имя пользователя должно содержать от 3 до 32 символов!';
    }

    if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]+/i',$_POST['username']))
    {
        $err[]='Ваше имя пользователя сожержит недопустимые символы!';
    }

    if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    {
        $err[]='Email не правильный!';
    }

    if(!count($err))
    {
        // Если нет ошибок

        $pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
        // Генерируем случайный пароль

        $_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        // Получаем введеные данные

        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO tz_members(usr,pass,email,regIP,dt)
                        VALUES(

                            '".$_POST['username']."',
                            '".md5($pass)."',
                            '".$_POST['email']."',
                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                            NOW()

                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            send_mail(  'demo-test@ruseller.com',
                        $_POST['email'],
                        'Регистрация в системе демонстрации - Ваш новый пароль',
                        'Ваш пароль: '.$pass);

            $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='Мы отправили вам письмо с вашим новым паролем!';
        }
        else $err[]='Данное имя пользователя уже занято!';
    }

    if(count($err))
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    }

    header("Location: demo.php");
    exit;
}

?>

А вот ajax обработчик и отправка формы

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#send-form').submit(function(){
        //при отправке формы собираем все данные из полей и ИД страницы
        var name = jQuery("input#username").val();
        var email = jQuery("input#email").val();
        //складываем все данные в одну строку (наш URL для AJAX-запроса)
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email;

    jQuery.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "demo.php",  //здесь указываем ИД ресурса, куда будет оправлен AJAX запрос
      data: dataString,
      success:  function() {  //сообщение об удачной отправке
                        jQuery('#send-form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                        jQuery('#message').html("<h2>Вы успешно зарегистрировались</h2>")  
                        .append("<p>Но для конечной регестрации вам надо подтвердить письмо отправленое вам на почту</p>")  
                        .hide()  
                        .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
                        $('#message').append("<i class=\"icon-ok\"></i>");  
                        });  
                } 
    });  
    return false;
                });
        });

</script>
```

по чему то не записываються данные в бд при нажатии на кнопку зарегестрироваться все испробовал ни как не могу сделать подскажите

Comment: Может стоит задуматься об отладке и локализовать ошибку(или научиться отлаживать и локализовывать)? Проверить происходит ли Ajax запрос, проверить ответ(может даже закомментировать код PHP и проверить на простой отдаче), выяснить значение пришедших данных, посмотреть значения переменных, выяснить какой именно sql запрос уходит и проверить его, проверить соединение с БД на простом статичном запросе. Это упростит жизнь не столько нам, сколько прежде всего Вам.

Comment: используйте pastebin.com, пожалуйста

Comment: просто используйте кнопку форматирования текста __{}__, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```
$_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); и т д  - это ж где такому учат???
username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])
```

по чему то не записываются данные в БД  - какие данные на сервер приходят - или не приходят? есть ли ошибки?